# Measuring the "flatness" of a function

Tags: functions, terminology

In some work I am doing, for a function $f$, I want to measure the average difference between two function values $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)|$ over the entire data distribution, $\int_X \int_X |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| dP(x_1) dP(x_2)$.  It seems to me that if the function is more "flat", then this measurement will be lower.  i.e. for the function $f(x) = c$, the measure would be 0, but for function $f(x) = x$ or $f(x) = sin(x)$, the measure would be high.

Is there some term used to measure this property of a function?

Answer (score 1):

There is a distance between random variables. Taking a separating class $\mathcal H$ you can define the distance between $F$ and $G$ via

$$d_\mathcal H(F,G) = \sup\{|E[h(F)]-E[h(G)]|: h \in \mathcal H\}$$

You can use for example

- $\mathcal H = \{ \mathbb 1_B: B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^d) \}$
- $\mathcal H = \{ h: h\text{ is Borel measurable and bounded}\}$

$\mathcal H$ is a separating class whenever from the fact, that $E[h(F)]=E[h(G)]$ for each $h\in \mathcal H$ with $h(F),h(G)\in L^1(\Omega)$ follows that $F$ and $G$ have the same distribution.

See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411/motivation-for-kolmogorov-distance-between-distributions) for other possibilities.